# for loop in synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to understand synchronization in java . I have following example,

```
public class TestThr implements Runnable {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

            Thread t=new Thread(new TestThr());
            Thread t1=new Thread(new TestThr());

            t.start();
            t1.start();
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
        sync();
   }

   public synchronized void sync(){
         for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("Running "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
   }

 }
```

```
Output :
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
```

From above example I was expecting one thread(whoever enter first) will complete the iteration and then second will start and complete but I'm getting inconsistent output .

Please add your opinion .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you search *Stack Overflow* for an explanation of what it means to synchronize a method?

Comment: @CKing sorry but I'm not able to understand behavior of synchronized method . To clarify same I asked .

Comment: Be sure to accept my answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From above example I was expecting one thread(whoever enter first) will complete the iteration and then second will start and complete but I'm getting inconsistent output .

You are getting output that you don't understand but it is consistent with the code you've written.  When you have a `synchronized` method, you are locking on the instance of the enclosing class.

```
public class TestThr implements Runnable {
   ...
   public synchronized void sync() {
```

In your example, the `sync` method is `synchronized` so it will lock on the particular instance of `TestThr`.   You are starting your threads like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new TestThr());
Thread t1 = new Thread(new TestThr());
```

This means that each of the threads has their own instance of `TestThr` so they are locking on different instances and don't stop each other from running.

If you instead did the following:

```
final TestThr testThr = new TestThr();
Thread t = new Thread(testThr);
Thread t1 = new Thread(testThr);
```

Now the 2 threads are working on the same instance of `TestThr` so they will be locking on the same object and your output will be what you expected.

This only works because `TestThr` does not have any fields that are stored.  If you need to have a more complex class then I'd pass in a lock object to them.  Something like:

```
final Object lockObject = new Object();
Thread t = new Thread(new TestThr(lockObject));
Thread t1 = new Thread(new TestThr(lockObject));
```

Then inside of your code you would do:

```
public void sync() {
   synchronized (lockObject) {
      ...
```

So the method would not be locked but you would synchronize on the shared lock object instead.

Btw, given the size of the loop, it is highly likely that one thread might start up and run through the loop and then exit before the other thread even starts.  Putting the `System.out.println(...)` call will slow the thread down so maybe you will get contention, but you need to worry about that if you remove the output.  It can be difficult to test threaded programs like this because of the race conditions between threads.

Answer (score 4):

This is:

```
public synchronized void sync(){
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("Running "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

works like this:

```
    public void sync(){
        synchronize(this) {
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                System.out.println("Running "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

So, in your case each thread synchronizes by different `TestThr` objects:

To see expected output you can try next:

```
public class TestThr implements Runnable {
    static SeparatedClass monitor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        monitor = new SeparatedClass();

        Thread t=new Thread(new TestThr());
        Thread t1=new Thread(new TestThr());

        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        monitor.sync();
    }
}

class SeparatedClass {
    public synchronized void sync(){
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("Running "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DullPointer That is what is being explained in this answer. You are locking on *this*. I am assuming you understand what *this* points to?

Comment: `this` doesn't point to `t` and `t1` @Pavlo.  It points to the 2 instances of `TestThr`.

Comment: Right! I made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pavlo ,Gray .

Answer (score 2):

As @Pavlo Plynko wrote, you are using synchronized method, but you have two different object created for Thread. You should create and single instance, and then provide this object to your threads. In that case, both threads will use the same instance of object and will wait for execution of the same method.

Following code:

```
public class TestThr implements Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestThr synchronizedObject = new TestThr();
    Thread t = new Thread(synchronizedObject);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(synchronizedObject);

    t.start();
    t1.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is waiting for execution");
    sync();
    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has executed synced method");
}

public synchronized void sync() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Running " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
}
```

Will provide following output:

```
Thread Thread-0 is waiting for execution
Thread Thread-1 is waiting for execution
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Running Thread-0
Thread Thread-0 has executed synced method
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Running Thread-1
Thread Thread-1 has executed synced method
```